# Editing in ListView without EditMode on

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a class

```
public class MyClass
{
public int id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
}
```

I store objects of type MyClass in list:

```
List<MyClass> listOfObjects {get; set;}
```

I want user to edit data. To display data I am using ListView control - I am binding listOfObject list to ListView:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
<LayoutTemplate>    
<table runat="server" id="table1" >       
<tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" >
</tr>     
</table>   
</LayoutTemplate>   
<ItemTemplate>     
<tr id="tr" runat="server">         
<td id="td1" runat="server">             
<asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' />         
</td>         
<td id="td2" runat="server">             
<asp:TextBox ID="tb2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name")%>' />        
</td>    
</tr>   
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:ListView>
```

So far so good, and everything works fine. I see the data in ListView.
I do not know how I can edit data in ListView without entering EditMode - I do not have Edit button, I have only textboxes to enter new data.
All I want is to bind data edited in textboxes in the opposite direction - into listOfObject list. I have tried many solutions
and nothing was working correctly...

I thought that I can read data this way:

```
var listItems = ListView1.Items.Cast<ListViewDataItem>().Select(a => new MyClass 
           {   
                id = ((TextBox)a.FindControl("tb1")).Text,   
                name = ((TextBox)a.FindControl("tb2")).Text   
           }).ToList<>();
```

but with this I get data which were in textbox before editing...

Help me please, because I have no idea how to make it working
**(maybe it would be better to use ObjectDataSource?)**

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call the last part of your code? I suppose you have a submit button, do you call that code in it's `Click` EventHandler?

You must be overwriting your data. If you DataBind in the Page's Load event make sure you only do that if the page is not posting back.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                 // databind
             }      
        }
```

Comment: yes, I am executing last part of the code in Click event of the button

Comment: Read my answer again, i added some info